# JavaFX - setFont() and setStyle() produce markedly different results. Why?

Tags: javafx-8

I've noticed that if I set the font of an object using setFont(), it always renders on the screen quite a bit smaller than if I set that same font using setStyle(). Why is this?

For Example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        FlowPane contentPane = new FlowPane();
        contentPane.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        Text setFontText = new Text("setFont(\"Courier\", 14)");
        setFontText.setFont(Font.font("Courier", 14));

        Text setStyleText = new Text("setStyle(\"-fx-font-family:Courier; -fx-font-size: 14pt\")");
        setStyleText.setStyle("-fx-font-family: Courier; -fx-font-size: 14pt");

        contentPane.getChildren().addAll(setFontText, setStyleText);

        primaryStage.setTitle("These Fonts Though");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(contentPane, 500, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This produces the following display:
[image: output]

Comment: If I add `System.out.println(setStyleText.getFont())`, it shows that the font for the text instance that is set by inline CSS has a size of 18.666 pt (on my system, I suspect this may vary). This looks like a bug...